create a subset array-of-struct column without exploding
new to pyspark. i have this example dataframe:
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    (("7dc88", "D21", 14.14, 2, 10, [["msgA", 15, "a"],["msgB", 9, "g"],["msgC", 6, "z"],["msgD", 4, "m"],["msgE", 1, "e"]]),
     ("1c36a3", "D21", 32.14, 18, 45, [["msgA", 45, "n"],["msgB", 30, "q"],["msgC", 24, "h"],["msgD", 19, "y"],["msgE", 11, "c"]])),
     "uniqueId : string, tag : string, score : float, time0 : int, time1 : int, msgs : array<struct<msg : string, time : int, sysid : string>>")


+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|uniqueId|tag|score|time0|time1|msgs                                                                       |
+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|7dc885  |D21|14.14|2    |10   |[{msgA, 15, a}, {msgB, 9, g}, {msgC, 6, z}, {msgD, 4, m}, {msgE, 1, e}]    |
|1c36a3  |D21|32.14|18   |45   |[{msgA, 45, n}, {msgB, 30, q}, {msgC, 24, h}, {msgD, 19, y}, {msgE, 11, c}]|
+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+

the msgs column is an array of struct (msg, time, sysid). (in my real use-case, the message structure has more elements and some are nested structures. also each uniqueId could have a couple hundred messages. and there are millions of uniqueIds.)
the time0 and time1 column specify an inclusive time range for a desired subset of the msgs. i need to create a new column msgs_subset that is ordered by time:
+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
|uniqueId|tag|score|time0|time1|msgs_subset                                                 |
+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
|7dc885  |D21|14.14|2    |10   |[{msgD, 4, m}, {msgC, 6, z}, {msgB, 9, g}]                  |
|1c36a3  |D21|32.14|18   |45   |[{msgD, 19, y}, {msgC, 24, h}, {msgB, 30, q}, {msgA, 45, n}]|
+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+

i'm able to create the msgs_subset column using this code:
df_msg_subset = (
    df
    .withColumn("msg_explode", F.explode(F.col("msgs")))
    .withColumn("msg_time", F.col("msg_explode.time"))
    .filter((F.col("msg_time") >= F.col('time0')) & (F.col("msg_time") <= F.col('time1')))
    .sort(F.col("uniqueId"), F.col("msg_time"))
    .groupBy(list(set(df.columns) - {'msgs'})).agg(F.collect_list('msg_explode').alias('msgs_subset'))
)

QUESTION: can this be done without exploding? i'm assuming that exploding (creating additional rows) only to then groupby/collapse them is expensive. how can i do the same using pyspark (not UDF) functions operating on msgs? it feels like it would be something like this, but i'm stuck on the create_subset_column function.
def create_subset_column(msgs, time0, time1):
    return F.sort_array(F.filter(...))

df_msg_subset = (
    df
    .withColumn("msgs_subset", create_subset_column("msgs", "time0", "time1"))
    .drop("msgs")
)

i'd appreciate any help/pointers.
AN EXAMPLE DF WHERE TIMES ARE EPOCH_MILLISEC
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
    (
        ("7dc88", "D21", 14.14, 1642970972787, 1642970985027, [
            ["msgA", 1642970990067, "a"],
            ["msgB", 1642970985027, "g"],
            ["msgC", 1642970978077, "z"],
            ["msgD", 1642970972787, "m"],
            ["msgE", 1642970960897, "e"],
        ]),
        ("1c36a3", "D21", 32.14, 1642971056787, 1642971074107, [
            ["msgA", 1642971080687, "n"],
            ["msgB", 1642971074107, "q"],
            ["msgC", 1642971068777, "h"],
            ["msgD", 1642971062157, "y"],
            ["msgE", 1642971056787, "c"],
        ])
    ),
    "uniqueId:string, tag:string, score:float, time0:long, time1:long, msgs:array<struct<msg:string, time:long, sysid:string>>"
)


Does this help?
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    (("7dc88", "D21", 14.14, 2, 10, [["msgA", 15, "a"],["msgB", 9, "g"],["msgC", 6, "z"],["msgD", 4, "m"],["msgE", 1, "e"]]),
     ("1c36a3", "D21", 32.14, 18, 45, [["msgA", 45, "n"],["msgB", 30, "q"],["msgC", 24, "h"],["msgD", 19, "y"],["msgE", 11, "c"]])),
     "uniqueId : string, tag : string, score : float, time0 : int, time1 : int, msgs : array<struct<msg : string, time : int, sysid : string>>")

Original:
+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|uniqueId|tag|score|time0|time1|msgs                                                                       |
+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|7dc88   |D21|14.14|2    |10   |[{msgA, 15, a}, {msgB, 9, g}, {msgC, 6, z}, {msgD, 4, m}, {msgE, 1, e}]    |
|1c36a3  |D21|32.14|18   |45   |[{msgA, 45, n}, {msgB, 30, q}, {msgC, 24, h}, {msgD, 19, y}, {msgE, 11, c}]|
+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+

     
df = (df.withColumn('msgs', expr("filter(msgs, msg -> ((msg.time >= time0) and (msg.time <= time1)))"))
        .withColumn("msgs", array_sort(expr("transform(msgs, x -> struct(x.time, x as original))")))
        .withColumn("msgs", expr("transform(msgs, x -> x.original)")))

df.show(truncate=False)

Transformed:
--------+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
|uniqueId|tag|score|time0|time1|msgs                                                        |
+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
|7dc88   |D21|14.14|2    |10   |[{msgD, 4, m}, {msgC, 6, z}, {msgB, 9, g}]                  |
|1c36a3  |D21|32.14|18   |45   |[{msgD, 19, y}, {msgC, 24, h}, {msgB, 30, q}, {msgA, 45, n}]|
+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+



A slightly shorter version:
df.withColumn('msgs_subset', F.expr("""
        filter(
            array_sort(msgs, (l,r) -> if(l.time < r.time, -1, if(l.time > r.time, 1, 0))),
            x -> x.time >= time0 and x.time <= time1
         )
        """ )) \
  .show(vertical=True, truncate=False)

Spark SQL's array_sort version accepts a comparator function as second parameter, so we can omit the two transforms.

thanks for this. unexpectedly, when i replace the time parameters with real values (epoch_milliseconds; i.e. long values), this returns cannot resolve 'array_sort(msgs, lambdafunction((namedlambdavariable().time - namedlambdavariable().time), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()))' due to data type mismatch: Return type of the given function has to be IntegerType;. i've added an example df to the original question in case you want to confirm.

The comparator function should return an integer. In the original answer it returned the difference between two timestamps which are now longs. Replacing the difference with an explicit if fixes the problem.
